# printTriangle with alphabets

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputNumber();
void printTriangle(int size, char ch[]);

int main()
{
    char arr_char[] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
    int number;
    number = inputNumber();
    printTriangle(number,arr_char);

    return 0;
}

int inputNumber()
{
    int size;
    printf("Input Size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("===\nTriangle Size is %d\n===\n",size);
    return size;
}

void printTriangle(int size, char ch[5])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if(j <= 4)
            {
                printf("%s ",ch[j]);
            }
            if(j > 4 )
            {
                printf("# ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is what it supposed to look like. And I'm confused as what I did wrong because it only work with inputNumber but not with printTriangle. a e i o u # # #  please go easy on me since I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" might help.

Comment: You should explain what the problem is...  when I run it with input size 1, it segfaults. Is that what you would help with?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segmentation fault is caused by an incorrect format string (%s should be %c).  The output format doesn't match expectations as the inner loop condition is wrong and you need a newline after you print each line (after inner loop):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 5

int inputNumber() {
    int size;
    printf("Input Size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("===\nTriangle Size is %d\n===\n",size);
    return size;
}

void printTriangle(int size, char ch[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%c ", j < LEN ? ch[j] : '#');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char arr_char[LEN] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
    int number;
    number = inputNumber();
    printTriangle(number,arr_char);
    return 0;
}
```

Consider using the type `unsigned` instead of `int` as negative size, row (`i`) and column (`j`) doesn't make sense.

Here is an alternatively implementation of `printTriangle()` that does a bit of work upfront to generate the last row, then use a prefix of that last row to print all rows:

```
void printTriangle(unsigned size, char ch[]) {
    // use malloc if size is large (say >4k),
    // or you don't want to use a variable length array (VLA)
    char str[2 * size]; 
    for(unsigned column = 0; column < size; column++) {
        str[2 * column] = column < LEN ? ch[column] : '#';
        str[2 * column + 1] = ' ';
    }
    for(unsigned row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        printf("%.*s\n", 2 * row + 1, str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it by changing it to %c but the next problem is that I can't seem to make the output like in the picture and can only make it all the same

Comment: You should file a new question if you need help with it (after you tried to solve it yourself).  The issue, btw, is that the inner loop in printTringle should be `j <=i`.  Posting the program in a moment.